# Pytest Selenium Allure report : Report multiple failures inside a same test

Tags: python, selenium, pytest, allure

**What I am trying to achieve:** If I have to validate multiple elements in the same page then I want to write multiple assertions under same test instead of writing multiple tests for opening browser and navigating to the page again and again for each assertions. Is it feasible and how we can achieve this?

**Solution I am using but not working** I am using allure report. When I use assert False or pytest.fail in both cases my allure report captures the failure but test case stops and further assertions or line of codes are not executed in that test. When I use pytest_check then it fails the test but failures are not captured in the allure report. it simply shows the step in green and test in red.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you do something from inside `allure.step` block failure will be marked with red or yellow (depends on the failure reason) **>** sign

```
with allure.step(description):
    do_something()
```

Comment: This works only if we do **assert False** or **allure.fail()**. but in both cases it will stop the execution and it will not continue. I want soft assertion to be reported and mark the test step fail in python pytest, allure.